# How do I make COUNT work how I need it to?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running this query, it works except it doesn't return what I need...

```
SELECT COUNT(up.profileOwnerUserNumber)
FROM profiles up
INNER JOIN userRatings ur
ON (ur.userRatingTargetUser = up.profileOwnerUserNumber)
WHERE ur.userRatingDateTime>(now()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

I get a return of 8 from this query.  It's counting all instances found where (ur.userRatingTargetUser = up.profileOwnerUserNumber).  But the userRatings table has 4 genuinely different entries in it - the other 4 are duplicates of numbers already found.  I want my COUNT to return 4 - the number of distinctly different ur.userRatingTargetUser numbers found, not all 8 entries.

```
Table userRatings:
userRatingNumber int (autoincrement)
userRatingTargetUser int

Table profiles:
profileNumber int (autoincrement)
profileOwnerUserNumber int
```

Both userRatingTargetUser and profileOwnerUserNumber have int values that can match because they are set using another table:

```
Table users:
userNumber int (autoincrement)
```

How do I change my query so that I no longer count these extra records?  SELECT DISTINCT didn't work.

Comment: Were you using DISTINCT the way Kevin suggested below?

Comment: You're not counting a column from userRatings, you're counting from profiles.  If you want distinct values from userRatings, try count(distinct ur.whateverYourColumnIs)...

Comment: count(distinct ) worked Andrew! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(up.profileOwnerUserNumber)
FROM profiles up
INNER JOIN userRatings ur
ON (ur.userRatingTargetUser = up.profileOwnerUserNumber)
WHERE ur.userRatingDateTime>(now()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY up.profileOwnerUserNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is an aggregate function, you should use GROUP BY.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html